# Different logic in Facets functionality

Tags: 7, views, search

what I am trying to achieve is to filter the site's search results and produce results of 5 content types. Search API has helped me do that and very well I must say. There is one more thing though that I need to do and I am wondering it already supports such behaviour and/or if it can be solved by theming OR if I have to create a custom solution; so here it is:

Say my aforementioned content types are: Alpha, Bravo, Charlie, Delta, Echo. I want my facets to be produced in this manner:

- All (23)
- Alpha (10)
- Bravo (4)
- Charlie (0)
- Delta (1)
- Echo (8)

So what i need furthermore than the options your module provides is the "All" option as long as showing Facets which yielded no results.

Apart from that, I also need to bypass the "filter-like" functionality the module provides by default, where I have to click the "-" sign next to the link to go back to the main selection, and make clicking the link filter the results while leaving the other options there for clicking. So if I was to switch from "All" to "Bravo" i'd just had to click Bravo, something like a contextual filter of Content Types in a View, oh and yes, my results are in a view-page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I did all of this with jQuery alone.

I created a block that contains the

- All (23)
- Alpha (10)
- Bravo (4)
- Charlie (0)
- Delta (1)
- Echo (8)

options, I add the number with jQuery by counting the grouped results, and by JQuery again, I hide the appropriate grouping blocks. So the Facet API block was of no use to me and neither was the View's exposed filter.

Comment: It would be better if you can explain how you achieved your needs.